# sql syntax error MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO order " + "(customerid, pant, shirt, date) " 
  + "VALUES ('"  + jTextField1.getText() + "','" + jTextField2.getText() 
  + "','" + jTextField3.getText() + "','" + jTextField4.getText() + "')";
```

When tried this, I got the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
    'order (customerid, pant, shirt, date) VALUES ('10','2','3','26')' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method).
```

Comment: This code is just begging for a SQL injection attack.  Do not use string concatenation for SQL, use PreparedStatements and query parameters for the love of humanity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) like `order` with backticks

```
INSERT INTO `order` (customerid, ...
```

Besides that I recommend using *Prepared Statements*.

Answer (score 0):

Table name "**order**" is reserve word so please change table name and try it.